# Google sheet script to remove rows based on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multiple-columns

I have created a Google Sheet with a messy mix of script and cell coding, with a purpose of assigning a lead to a specialist when prompted and operate in a round robin style selection so that the leads are distributed evenly.

How it works:

- Button triggers function
- Message boxes prompt for 2 questions, if the lead is in english or french, and the current time is before or after 5PM EST. Based on this input it will select one of 3 employee arrays defined in the sheet 'Employees' (which would be hidden)
- From there, the user facing page 'Schedule' pulls the name of the assigned specialist and lists it
- When the same function is called next time, the list in sheet 'Employees' will check on the list in sheet 'Schedule' and not repeat the same name from that array

  - Data is also captured on a seperate sheet 'Responses' so if cells are cleared in the sheet 'Schedule', historical data is logged for later use

What I need:

- When all names in one of the array's is completed, all rows in column C of the sheet 'Schedules' would be cleared. This would change based on user input but this column might contain names from more than 1 array. So if leads are distributed to every member of the array then the list would start over
- I have tried various methods of if/else if statements and the delete row function but nothing has worked properly

Here is a link to my worksheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oLjbA-UzsW2ee_zOEfGBABz9sNNIHJkTMQ7YfPT8SS4/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is really appreciated... I have been going in circles with this!!!

I used the below script to check column C for a single name if found and delete it, but this dosent help for more than the one variable:

```
 var rowsDeleted = 0;   for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
       var row = values[i];
       if (row[2] == 'Fabien Mariou') {
         s2.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
         rowsDeleted++;
       }}
```

Comment: so you want to change your script so that it works with more than 1 name at a time, if I understand well?

Comment: @LioraHaydont I am looking for a way to have the script either remove the rows from the column once all the names in the given array are listed (so the sheet can pull data from the top of the array again), or loop to the begining of the given array to display the assigned name